# How to denormalize normalized data most effectively in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, normalization, denormalization

For example I have the following tree:

```
root: {
  a: {
    b: null,
    c: {
      d: null
    }
  }
  e: null
}
```

I receive it in the shape of `{ [child]: parent }`:

```
{
  a: 'root',
  e: 'root',
  b: 'a',
  c: 'a',
  d: 'c'
}
```

But I don't receive it ordered as above. However, I would like to.

If I know that the root item (that doesn't have a parent) is `root`, I can work with this function:

```
const recurs = (obj, cb, parent = 'root') => Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([child, childsParent]) => childsParent === parent)
  .forEach(([child]) => {
    cb(child);
    recurs(obj, cb, child);
  });
```

But because it's recursive, it can fill the memory because the parents won't be garbage collected until everything finishes. Is there a more efficient way to do this kind of things? Can this be converted to a for loop?

Comment: "*Can this be converted to a for loop?*" yes it can. However, why do you think that will help the garbage collection? Usually GC will wait until something like a loop finishes before it runs. Have you actually observed a problem or is this premature optimisation?

Comment: It's based on my (far from stable) knowledge of if a block has finished running, it will be automatically garbage collected. So I assume because a for loop's body is a block, it will be collected immediately after it ran its iteration. Is it wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "*it can fill the memory because the parents won't be garbage collected*"?

Comment: There is no guarantee when GC will run. It does usually wait for the program to not be busy. It *might* run during a loop but usually that leads to vastly degraded performance (if it runs once, chances are it will run more times. with a large loop that will produce a lot of GC eligible stuff, that's going to be a lot of GC stops).

Comment: This brings us back to "have you actually noticed it being a problem" because right now it sounds like you're trying to optimize something that doesn't have an actual performance or usability (dev _or_ user) issues, and so doesn't need any time spent on it.

Comment: I think perhaps the OP is concerned with the call stack rather than GC since the question is about avoiding recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookup table that is filled in a single linear loop:

```
const edges = {
  a: 'root',
  e: 'root',
  b: 'a',
  c: 'a',
  d: 'c'
};

const forest = {};
for (const child in edges) {
  const parent = edges[child];
  forest[parent] ??= {};
  forest[child] ??= {};
  forest[parent][child] = forest[child];
}
const tree = forest.root;
```